# How to build specific format with open()?

Tags: python, csv

Here's my code:

```
import glob
import itertools
import sys, os
import six
import csv
import numpy as np
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

os.chdir("PATH/pdf")

extension = 'pdf'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
valeur = []
n = 1
for i in all_filenames:
    fp = open(i, "rb")
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog["AcroForm"])["Fields"]
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get("T"), field.get("V")
        filehehe = "{0}:{1}".format(name,value)
        values = resolve1(value)
        names = resolve1(name)
        valeur.append(values)
    n = n+1

with open('test.csv','wb') as f:
    for i in valeur:
        f.write(i)
```

The goal here is to pick up some informations in PDF. Here's the output :

[image: output]

As you can see, the format is not pretty. I'm not very familiar with `open()` so I'm kind of stuck.

I would like to have distinct rows for each PDF with each informations having her own cell. Something like that :

[image: outputdesired]

Comment: If you want to create a CSV output file, I suggest you use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and thanks for the edit :) Have a nice day sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to store the data from each pdf file in a separate list. And add this list to the `valeur` list which you have.
2. Use `csv` module as @martineau rightly suggested.

You can try the with below code.

```
import csv
valeur = []

#your code

n = 1
for i in all_filenames:
    temp_list = []
    fp = open(i, "rb")
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog["AcroForm"])["Fields"]
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get("T"), field.get("V")
        filehehe = "{0}:{1}".format(name,value)
        values = resolve1(value)
        names = resolve1(name)
        temp_list.append(values)
    n = n+1
    valeur.append(temp_list)

#Finally when you have the required data, you can write to csv file like this.
with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for val in valeur:
        wr.writerow(val)
```

With this, the output would be like this

[image]

Comment: I cannot append like that because my script look for value into pdf.

Comment: Anima300: You will need to change how that part of your script works because this shows how the information will need to be organized in order to make the format look "pretty" the way you want.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try to do that, thanks sir

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check how temp_list is used.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot sir, have a nice day :) (answer upvoted and accepted)